# C++ current function name as string

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there any way to get current function name in C++? I want to track some functions calls order. Is there something like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
__FUNCTION__
//or
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

Comment: Thanks, it works:) It's very useful for render functions that you can't debug nice with breakpoints

Comment: Is this macro compatible with compilers other than GCC?

Comment: @Sampath, as it is not standard there's no guarantee to that, but it is listed for example in msdn docs for Microsoft compiler. So I assume it is supported in most compilers. However using __func__ might be better as this macro is defined in standard and should be universally supported.

Comment: what is the difference between __FUNCTION__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, just out of curiosity?

Comment: per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Function-Names.html - __FUNCTION__ prints just function name, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ prints language-specific format (e.g. containing return type, parameter types)

Answer (score 10):

Or if you want to be compatible with the soon-to-be (sic) C++0x standard, use `__func__`, if your compiler supports it (GCC does), which will be portable.

Comment: Or, it you want to be compatible with the _current_ standard: `#ifdef MYFN`, `#undef MYFN`, `#endif`, `#define MYFN nameofmyfunction` before every function you write :-)